# Does the untarred folder overwrites or appends the contents of the original folder?

Tags: linux, backup, tar

I have a `x.tar.gz` as a backup which has the following contents:

```
.htaccess
a.html
b.html
c.html
x.html
```

I have also a `./x` directory, already existing, which has the following contents:

```
.htaccess
a.html
b.html
c.html
y.html
```

Now, if I `tar xzf` the tar file in the same location, what will be the contents of the `./x` directory?

Comment: Yes, it will overwrite the content of the `x/` folder.

Comment: Please refine the question and define what you mean by overwriting or appending.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It's arguably clear what he means. I think the question is kinda in the realm of beginner's questions.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  It was not clear when I commented. In a Mac when you copy over in the interface a directory in top of another one the directory effectively is destroyed, e.g. all files disappear. The doubt could come from that. I prefer the OPs to detail their problems, than wasting time trying to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it (at least the tar program) will overwrite existing files (it won't append anything):

```
$ mkdir x
$ echo hello >x/file
$ tar cvfz x.tar.gz x
x/
x/file
$ echo world >x/file
$ tar xvfz x.tar.gz
x/
x/file
$ cat x/file
hello
```

Since you've rewrote your question the answer is that the existing files .htaccess, a.html, b.html, c.html will be replaced with the versions in x.tar.gz.

The existing file y.html will not be touched.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `--confirmation` option from the `tar` command. For example:

```
$> tar xvf --confirmation x.tar.gz
```

Comment: Yes that's a good option although my query wasn't about the 'confirmation' option really.

Comment: In fact, there is no real alternative... You cannot rename or send the decompression in another place.

Comment: While yes you are right in saying that but there are beginner's workaround I guess. 1. Rename existing `/x` to `/x1`. 2. Extract the tar file. 3. Make a `diff` comparison between x and x1  4. Keep the desired folder. Am I correct?

Comment: @Rammath: Yes, you are correct. But, I thought you were expecting something inside the `tar` command.

Comment: No probs. I came to know a bit more, like the `confirmation` option :-)